# Asus fan control not working, does not find Kernel module

Tags: drivers, kernel, asus, fan, fancontrol

**Problem**:

I have an Asus UX3410U laptop with ubuntu 18.04.1 (kernel 5.4.0-74-generic). Since a few days the fan control doesn't work anymore in ubuntu probably due to an update (it still works in bios). The fan works very hard and is noisy, but sensors show temperatures between (37-50°C). hardinfo shows that the 'asus-nb-wmi/fan1' does 25500RPM.

`pwmconfig` returns:
`/usr/sbin/pwmconfig: There are no pwm-capable sensor modules installed`

`modinfo nct6775` returns:
`filename:       /lib/modules/5.4.0-74-generic/kernel/drivers/hwmon/nct6775.ko`
(And the rest of the information.) So the nct6775 module exists.

but `modprobe nct6775` returns:
`modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'nct6775': No such device`

It seems that nct6775 exists, but cannot be loaded.

**Question**
How can I tell pwmconfig how to find the nct6775 module?

**More information:**

`sensors` returns

```
asus-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
cpu_fan:     25500 RPM

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Package id 0:  +39.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 0:        +39.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:        +39.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
```

The /etc/fancontrol reads:

```
INTERVAL=5
DEVPATH=hwmon0=devices/platform/coretemp.0 hwmon2=devices/platform/eeepc
DEVNAME=hwmon0=coretemp hwmon2=eeepc
FCTEMPS= hwmon2/pwm1=hwmon0/temp1_input
FCFANS= hwmon2/pwm1=
MINTEMP= hwmon2/pwm1=55
MAXTEMP= hwmon2/pwm1=65
MINSTART= hwmon2/pwm1=50
MINSTOP= hwmon2/pwm1=35
MINPWM= hwmon2/pwm1=0
MAXPWM= hwmon2/pwm1=155
```

In `/sys/class/hwmon/hwmon3/` I don't have files starting with pwm.

In `/sys/devices/platform/asus-nb-wmi/` I don't have a file fan_boost_mode and cannot touch one.

**What else did I try so far:**

- add `acpi_enforce_resources=lax` to 'GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=' in /etc/default/grub
- add `nct6775` to /etc/modules
- removed and reinstalled lm-sensors and fancontrol
- followed this [solution tutorial](https://www.reddit.com/r/ZephyrusG14/comments/kt9mvb/ubuntu_fan_control_or_how_to_disable_fans/)
- when I start with the old kernel 4.15.0-144-generic, I still have the same problems, but the output of `sensors` changes to

```
pch_skylake-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +39.5°C  

acpitz-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +43.0°C  (crit = +103.0°C)

iwlwifi_1-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +44.0°C  

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Package id 0:  +43.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 0:        +43.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:        +42.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
```